# How to make use of props in a more efficient way?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql

I have a code in which I receive the values ​​of two dropdown and then I make a request to my graphql by GET method with AXIOS. I would like to know if I can use props to not do that kind of thing? How could I do it?.

There are two dropdown and if I select the day and the month, I should leave the results without reloading the entire page.

Here are some pictures of how this works:

Select day and/or month:

[image: Sample image]

The result and the request with Axios:

[image: Sample image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import format from 'date-fns/format';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import Divider from '../Divider';
import TituloSmall, { types } from '../TituloSmall';
import Titulo from '../Titulo';
import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './style.css';


import {
  ButtonDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
} from 'reactstrap';
import { addMonths } from 'date-fns';
import axios from 'axios';

const query0 = gql`
  query postsDiaComoHoy($dia: Int!, $mes: Int!) {
    posts(first: 2, dia: $dia, mes: $mes, categoria: 28) {
      rows {
        id
        fecha_dia_hoy
        imagen_intro
        titulo
        introtext
        autor
        fulltext
        fulltext2
        imagen_banner
        categoria {
          id
        }
        tags {
          id
          titulo
        }
      }
      count
    }
  }
`;

const renderTagItem = item => {
  const { id, titulo } = item;
  return (
    <Link key={id} to={`/tags/${id}/`}>
      <div className="tag">{titulo}</div>
    </Link>
  );
};

const removeTagHtml = valor => valor.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, '');
const removerTwitter = valor => valor.replace(/- @\w+/g, '');

var updated = 0;
var dates = format(Date(), 'D'),
  month = format(Date(), 'M');
export class dayScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentIndex: 0,
      sortItem1: month,
      sortItem2: dates,
      cantidadMeses: [
        'Enero',
        'Febrero',
        'Marzo',
        'Abril',
        'Mayo',
        'Junio',
        'Julio',
        'Agosto',
        'Septiembre',
        'Octubre',
        'Noviembre',
        'Diciembre',
      ],
      diasMes: [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30,
        31,
      ],
    };
  }

  state = {
    error: null,
    items: [],
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.getAnime();
    this.render();
    updated = 0;
  }

  getAnime = async () => {
    const changeArticles = `
    {
      posts(first: 3, dia: ${dates}, mes: ${month}) {
        rows {
          id
          fecha_dia_hoy
          imagen_intro
          titulo
          introtext
          autor
          views
          fulltext
          fulltext2
          imagen_banner
            categoria {
            id
          }
          tags{
            id
            titulo
          }
          }
        count
      }
    }
    `;
    if (updated) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          'http://localhost:4000/graphql/?query=' + changeArticles,
        );

        // Log the response so we can look at it in the console

        // Set the data to the state
        this.setState(() => ({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: response.data.data.posts.rows,
        }));
        this.props.data.posts.rows = this.state.items;
      } catch (error) {
        // If there's an error, set the error to the state
        this.setState(() => ({ error }));
        console.log(this.state.error);
      }
    }
  };

  selectIndex = direction => {
    const { currentIndex } = this.state;
    const {
      data: {
        posts: { count },
      },
    } = this.props;

    let nexIndex = currentIndex + direction;
    nexIndex = nexIndex < 0 ? count - 1 : nexIndex;
    nexIndex = nexIndex >= count ? 0 : nexIndex;
    this.setState({ currentIndex: nexIndex });
  };

  monthSelected() {
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen1: !this.state.dropdownOpen1,
    });
    if (this.state.dropdownOpen1) {
      this.props.data.variables.mes = this.state.sortItem1;
      this.props.data.variables.dia = this.state.sortItem2;
      month = this.state.sortItem1;
      dates = this.state.sortItem2;
      updated = 1;
    }
  }

  dateSelected() {
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen2: !this.state.dropdownOpen2,
    });
    if (this.state.dropdownOpen2) {
      this.props.data.variables.mes = this.state.sortItem1;
      this.props.data.variables.dia = this.state.sortItem2;
      month = this.state.sortItem1;
      dates = this.state.sortItem2;
      updated = 1;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    if (data.loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    if (data.error) {
      return <div>{data.error.message}</div>;
    }

    if (data.posts.rows.length <= 0) {
      return <div>Nada que mostrar...</div>;
    }
    const {
      data: {
        posts: { rows },
      },
    } = this.props;

    const { currentIndex } = this.state;
    const item = rows[currentIndex];

    let html = item.fulltext + item.fulltext2;
    const description = item.introtext.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '');
    const image = `${process.env.REACT_APP_IMG_BASE}${item.imagen_intro ||
      item.imagen_banner}`;

    return (
      <div className="containerDiaComoHoyNoticia">
        <div className="box">
          <span />
          <span />
          <div className="mesTexto">
            {this.state.cantidadMeses[this.state.sortItem1 - 1]}
          </div>
          <div className="diaTexto">{this.state.sortItem2}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="textoContainer">
            <div className="tituloDiaComoHoyNoticia">
              {'BUSCA QUE OCURRIÓ EL DÍA QUE TU QUIERAS EN EL FÚTBOL'}
            </div>
            <div className="separatorLinea"></div>
            <div className="listaMesDia">
              <span className="circuloMesDia">1</span>
              <span>Mes</span>
              <ButtonDropdown
                isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen1}
                toggle={() => {
                  this.monthSelected();
                }}>
                <DropdownToggle color="white" caret>
                  {this.state.sortItem1}
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu>
                  {this.state.cantidadMeses.map((items, i) => (
                    <DropdownItem
                      dropDownValue="Mes"
                      onClick={e => {
                        this.state.sortItem1 = e.target.innerHTML;
                      }}>
                      {i + 1}
                    </DropdownItem>
                  ))}
                </DropdownMenu>
              </ButtonDropdown>
              <span className="circuloMesDia">2</span>
              <span>Dia</span>

              <ButtonDropdown
                isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen2}
                toggle={() => {
                  this.dateSelected();
                }}>
                <DropdownToggle caret>{this.state.sortItem2}</DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu>
                  {this.state.diasMes.map(i => (
                    <DropdownItem
                      dropDownValue="Mes"
                      onClick={e => {
                        this.state.sortItem2 = e.target.innerHTML;
                      }}>
                      {i}
                    </DropdownItem>
                  ))}
                </DropdownMenu>
              </ButtonDropdown>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {rows.map((item, index) => (
          <div className="listaNoticiasContenido">
            <img
              alt={item.titulo}
              src={process.env.REACT_APP_IMG_BASE + item.imagen_intro}
              className="listaNoticiasImagen"
            />
            <div className="rectanguloIconoPlay"></div>
            <div className="contenidoArticulo">
              <div className="tituloArticulo">{item.titulo}</div>
              <div className="descripcionArticulo">
                {removeTagHtml(item.introtext)}
              </div>
              <div className="escritor">
                <div className="nombreAutor">
                  <div>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="user-circle" />
                    <span className="autorArticulo">
                      {removerTwitter(item.autor) || 'Sin autor'}
                    </span>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="eye" />
                    <span className="vistasTotalesArticulos">{item.views}</span>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="calendar" />
                    <span className="cantidadArticulosEscritos">
                      {item.fecha_dia_hoy}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>              <div className="separadorArticulos"></div>

          </div>
        ))}
        <h2 className="titulo">{item.titulo}</h2>
        <div className="titlesContainer">
          <TituloSmall
            iconName="user-circle"
            label={item.autor || 'Sin autor'}
          />
          <TituloSmall
            iconName="calendar"
            label={format(item.fecha_dia_hoy, 'DD/MM/YYYY')}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="imageIntro">
          <img className="imageDescription" src={image} alt={item.titulo} />
          <div class="esquinaFigura">
            <div className="boxWhite">
              <span />
              <span />
              <div className="mesTextoBoxWhite">
                {this.state.cantidadMeses[this.state.sortItem1 - 1]}
              </div>
              <div className="diaTextoBoxWhite">{this.state.sortItem2}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <article dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
        <TituloSmall iconName="tags" label="Tags" type={types.BIG} />
        {item.tags.map(item => renderTagItem(item))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

dayScreen.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    error: PropTypes.shape({ message: PropTypes.string }),
  }).isRequired,
};

dayScreen.defaultProps = {};

const queryOptions = {
  options: () => ({
    variables: {
      dia: dates,
      mes: month,
    },
  }),
};

export default graphql(query0, queryOptions)(dayScreen);
```

How could I do this without Axios? When doing it with Axios, is this scalable? I have been told that the props are for that, but I do not know how to do it.

I would like to do this without Axios and only using props. Receive the value of the dropdowns and change that part of the page doing the query with graphql.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing `Apollo Client`, start by installing [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) and then set it up in your project following the documentation.

Comment: If you need to do just one GraphQl call then it does not matter what you are using to fetch data (Axios is fine), but if you need to do more than one graphql call it will be better to set up apollo.